# How to add a scaling policy to an auto scaling group using Cloud Formation or AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

How to add a scaling policy to an auto scaling group either new or existing using Cloud Formation or AWS CLI

Comment: Maybe one of the [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-autoscaling.html) will help.

Answer (score 2):

There are a significant examples of this, but below is a snippet from one of my existing cloud formation templates.

**1) Parameters**
You should take minimum and maximum as a parameter

**2) The autoscale group itself**
I include it below, but if you didn't want to include it you could take it as a parameter.  You can also use a condition that would either use the existing of the parameter as a condition to determine whether the ASG should be created. Please note if you do use the condition, you will also use that condition on all references with an in statement (to determine if using local ASG in template or the parameter).

**3) Alarms**
This is the key element of auto-scale group - determining the alarms.  I'm using memory reservation of the cluster, but I would say CPU is the most common.  You can use any metric cloudwatch monitors and even custom metrics.

**4) Policy**
I'm currently quickly reacting up and down...it takes about 30-60s for a new instance to make an impact and that is why I have 120s between events.  You need to understand your system to correctly choose the right amount to avoid over scaling.

```
ECSClusterAutoScalingGroup:
  Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
  Condition: notDedicated
  Properties:
    VPCZoneIdentifier:
    - 'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${VPC}-PrivateSubnet1'
    - 'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${VPC}-PrivateSubnet2'
    - 'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${VPC}-PrivateSubnet3'
    MinSize: !Ref MinSize
    MaxSize: !Ref MaxSize
    HealthCheckGracePeriod: '600'
    HealthCheckType: EC2
    LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref ECSLaunchConfiguration
    MetricsCollection:
    - Granularity: 1Minute
ECSClusterScaleOutPolicy:
  Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy'
  Condition: AutoScaleNotDedicated
  Properties:
    AdjustmentType: ChangeInCapacity
    AutoScalingGroupName: !Ref ECSClusterAutoScalingGroup
    Cooldown: '120'
    ScalingAdjustment: '1'
ECSClusterScaleOutAlarm:
  Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
  Condition: AutoScaleNotDedicated
  Properties:
    EvaluationPeriods: '1'
    Statistic: Average
    Threshold: '70'
    AlarmDescription: Scale up alarm when Memory Reservation > 70% for 1 minute
    Period: '60'
    AlarmActions:
    - !Ref ECSClusterScaleOutPolicy
    Namespace: AWS/ECS
    Dimensions:
    - Name: ClusterName
      Value: !Ref ECSCluster
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
    MetricName: MemoryReservation
ECSClusterScaleInPolicy:
  Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy'
  Condition: AutoScaleNotDedicated
  Properties:
    AdjustmentType: ChangeInCapacity
    AutoScalingGroupName: !Ref ECSClusterAutoScalingGroup
    Cooldown: '120'
    ScalingAdjustment: '-1'
ECSClusterScaleInAlarm:
  Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
  Condition: AutoScaleNotDedicated
  Properties:
    EvaluationPeriods: '1'
    Statistic: Average
    Threshold: '45'
    AlarmDescription: Scale down alarm when Memory Reservation <= 45% for 5 minutes
    Period: '300'
    AlarmActions:
    - !Ref ECSClusterScaleInPolicy
    Namespace: AWS/ECS
    Dimensions:
    - Name: ClusterName
      Value: !Ref ECSCluster
    ComparisonOperator: LessThanOrEqualToThreshold
    MetricName: MemoryReservation
```